# No password required for sudo over ssh the second time

Tags: ssh, sudo

On my own machine if I start a new terminal and I perform something that requires superuser rights I have to enter my password.

However, if I login to a remote machine **a second time**, this is not required, how is that possible? Is this the same shell?

```
ssh remote_machine
sudo su
# enter password
# drop out of the remote shell entirely
ssh remote_machine # again
sudo su
# now continue without typing a password!
```

How is this possible?

Comment: doesn't work here. are you sure it works? which ssh/sudo/... version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. Please, notice that I am not talking about the SSH password (I use keys anyways). I am talking about your password to get sudo rights.

Comment: yes, i'm aware of that (and i used ssh-keys with an ssh-agent for my test as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From sudo home page (http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html):

sudoers uses time stamp files for credential caching. Once a user has been authenticated, the time stamp is updated and the user may then use sudo without a password for a short period of time (5 minutes unless overridden by the timeout option). **By default**, sudoers uses a tty-based time stamp which means that there is a separate time stamp for each of a user's login sessions. **The tty_tickets option can be disabled to force the use of a single time stamp for all of a user's sessions**.

It is probably what's happening.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. There is no `Defaults !tty_tickets` defined in `/etc/sudoers` though. Is there an other way in which this option can be disabled?

Comment: Weird, `sudo -ll` gives: `Matching Defaults entries for **me** on this host:
    env_reset` 
and no other default entries... And in specific not `tty_tickets`, so that explains it indeed. The only thing awkward is why there are so few default settings properly set.

Comment: Did you check ``/etc/sudoers.d`` ?

Comment: Yes, there is only a `README` file in there. I searched for `sudoers` on the entire disk. There is no other config file. Anyway `man sudoers` also tells this: `When the tty_tickets option is enabled, the time stamp has per-tty gran‐
     ularity but still may outlive the user's session.`